# Zend Form - two select menus in "sync"

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework, select, synchronization

I have been trying to find out an answer for some time and still nothing.
There are two select menus, they have the same amount of options and values. Say

```
Select A
"one"=>1
"two"=>2
"three"=>3
Select B
"one"=>One
"two"=>Two
"three"=>Three
```

Is there a way with Zend Form and validate to make them "synced". 
So If I select SelectB=>Three, it automatically selects SelectA=>3 and vice-versa.
Or only with a custom validator?

Comment: you could do it after the post with an `if isset then setvalue loop` but if you need it before the post you'll need javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript solution works like this:

1. Modify your form.php

   `$A->setOptions(array('onchange'=>'mapIt(this.id)')); 
   $B->setOptions(array('onchange'=>'mapIt(this.id)'));`

**and**

1. Add below JavaScript function to your view

`function mapIt(id){

if(id == 'A'){
document.getElementById('B').value  =   document.getElementById(id).value;
}else{
document.getElementById('A').value  =   document.getElementById(id).value;
}
}`